# In a list of datetime index,how to detect if two index are consecutive and drop the first one

Tags: python, date, datetime, python-datetime

I have a little problem with a part of my script.
I want to drop the first date in this following list of DatetimeIndex if there are consecutive days.

```
In [110]:fault_point
Out[110]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2013-11-05, ..., 2014-05-12]
```

Length: 3, Freq: None, Timezone: None

For exemple fault_point will contain:

```
2013-11-05 00:00:00
2013-11-06 00:00:00
2014-05-12 00:00:00
```

And since  2013-11-05 00:00:00 and  2013-11-05 00:00:00 are consecutive days,I want to have as output:

```
2013-11-06 00:00:00
2014-05-12 00:00:00
```

Comment: The objects in the DatetimeIndex are datetime64 objects. Difference of any two datetime64 objects would return timedelta64. Why not check the value of timedelta64 object and drop an entry if required.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this which converts your text dates into datetime format then extract elements that are not one day before the following date in the list :

```
>>> from datetime import *
>>> mydates = ['2013-11-05 00:00:00', '2013-11-06 00:00:00', '2014-05-12 00:00:00']
>>> thedates = map(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"),mydates)
>>> [x for x in thedates if thedates.index(x) == (len(thedates)-1) or (thedates[thedates.index(x)+1]-x).days > 1]
[datetime.datetime(2013, 11, 6, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 12, 0, 0)]
```